# console.log PhoneGap 3.1 on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, console.log

I try to use console.log in my Phonegap 3.1 application.
I installed the console plugin, doing this:

phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git

Unfortunately when I examined the source of the plugin there are no src files for Android... should there be some. 
My console.log still doesn't appear in ADB LogCat.

Thansk for any help,
ToM

Comment: if you look at the unfiltered log? My console.log() was written with the TAG "WebView"

Comment: In my case no entries with this tag.